# I can't seem to display the background image. The background Image shows up for a split second but then crash 'failed to execute CreateElement'

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I try to change the backgroundImage based on the time but using a function if-else with document.body.style.backgroundImage

I have looked at the console log to look further into it. The picture shows up and the background image is properly in the html body styles = but it keeps giving me an error saying that failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document'

```
import React from 'react';

import lo from "/Users/justinandhang/Desktop/menu/menu2/src/photo/lo.png"


function ClockImage() {
    const date = new Date()
    const hours = date.getHours()
    let timeOfDay
    if (hours < 12) {
        return document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("'+lo+'")'

    }
    else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 17) {
        return document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("${lo}")`
    }else {
        return document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/Users/justinandhang/Desktop/menu/menu2/src/photo/lo.png")'     
    }


}

export default ClockImage()
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import MenuContainer from "./MenuContainer"
import city from "/Users/justinandhang/Desktop/menu/menu2/src/photo/turntable_vignette.gif"
import lo from "/Users/justinandhang/Desktop/menu/menu2/src/photo/lo.png"
import ClockImage from "/Users/justinandhang/Desktop/menu/menu2/src/ClockImage.js"



ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <ClockImage />
        <MenuContainer />
    </div>
    , document.getElementById('container'));
```

The error says that Invalid Character Error: Failed to execute 'CreateElement' on 'Document'.

I have tried 3 different way to link the url differently but it returns the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are exporting `ClockImage()` which call the function first then exports the returned value, and in `index.js` React fails to render `ClockImage` because it's not a component.

You need to export `ClockImage` instead:

```
export default ClockImage;
```

A side note: it's not a good idea to create/render a component just for the sole purpose of changing the style.

Comment: Thank you so much! What way should I go about to change the style without creating a function?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with calling a function that changes the style, it's more the fact that you were trying to render as if it were a component.
You can instead call that function inside `componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate` of the Root component, or you can just call it in your index.js